# French Pass Sanitaire for travelers coming from outside the EU

Tags: france, covid-19

I need to travel to France in August. It has just been announced that starting in August, the "pass sanitaire" will be required to board trains and enter restaurants.

I will be fully vaccinated, so in theory, I should be allowed to access these things without a test. However, having been vaccinated outside the EU (in Canada), it is not clear that my vaccines will be recognized in restaurants and trains, even though they will most probably be recognized by border control agents at the airport.

Can vaccinated non-european tourists have their vaccination recognized in France in a way that allows them to access places and events where a "pass sanitaire" is required?

Comment: The details of the implementation of these restrictions (legal framework and tools) for bars and restaurants are yet to be defined. This was cited in yesterday's speech as the reason to wait for August, whereas restrictions on larger venues will apply from next week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes since the 9th of august.
All pieces of information are gathered [on this page of the french diplomacy department](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/le-ministere-et-son-reseau/actualites-du-ministere/informations-coronavirus-covid-19/demande-de-passe-sanitaire-en-cas-de-vaccination-a-l-etranger-procedure-pour-64244/). I tried to find a english version of that page, but I did not find it...

< start of rapid translation as of august 16th >

Starting 15 august, this process is open to foreign non-EU tourists, already in France or arriving until 18th august 2021. Demands relating to arrival after this date will be handled later.

Reminder: a temporary QR Code can be generated by an healthcare professionnal after a negative PCR test or antigenic test (see below).

If you've been vacinated in the EU, andore, Island, Liechtenstein, Monaco, Norway or UK (England and Wales), Suiss, your country gives you a EU numerical certificate of that will be accepted in France.
Otherwise, you may ask for a "pass sanitaire" if you fullfill one of the conditions listed on that page:

- you do not originate from a country of the EU.
- you are 18 or older. Until september 30th, the "pass sanitaire" is not required for young people aged 12 to 17. Nothing is required for child less than 12 years old.
- You are vacinated by a vacine endorsed by the European Medicines Agency or equivalent (link in the original page). Tha means more than 4 weeks have elasped for single-dose vacine such as Johnson&Johnson or more than 7 days after the second dose for other (Pfitzer, Moderna, AstraZeneca) or more than 7 days after the single shot you got if you had recovered from Covid19.
- You already are in France or in the EU or you plan to come within a few days.

To ask for the pass, you have to fill a [form](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/demande_de_conversion_de_certificat_de_vaccination_cle06bfeb-2.pdf). You need to provide, name, firstname, adress, country where you got the shot, date of arrival in France, date of departure, email, phone number (including regional index). The date must be added to the form and it must be signed. Along with the form, you must send a copy of your valid passport, a copy of the certificate of vacination, that must clearly state which vacine has been used, and a copy of your transportation ticket.
These pieces of information and the form must be sent using pdf, jpg or png. Do not use zip: it wil not be handled. It must be sent to the following address, depending on where you live:

- If you come from the United States: area1.covid-pass@diplomatie.gouv.fr
- If you come from Canada: area2.covid-pass@diplomatie.gouv.fr
- If you come from elsewhere: area3.covid-pass@diplomatie.gouv.fr

The title of your mail must be formated that way :

COUNTRY / NAME Firstname / Date of arrival DD-MM-21

For instance:

USA / DURAND Anne / 27-08-21

Incomplete demands will not be handled. You must restart and resend everything. Don't forget to send the form!
You mail must not be bigger than 10MB.
Once your demand is handled, you will receive an email containing a QR Code. It could be printed and presented on paper, or added to the TousAntiCovid application, to justify that you got the shot.

FAQ:
->We are many. Should each one of us fill and send a separe form?
Yes. Each person must fill and sign a form and provide the corresponding pieces of information (passport, vacination certificate, transportation ticket). Each demand must be sent separately, in a separate email.

->When will I receive my QR code?
We are facing a huge number of demands. We are trying to handle it rapidely. Do not send reminders, it may delay the process.

->Why did I not received my QR code yet?
We are doing everything to rapidely handle the demands. In some cases, we must perform additionnal checks on provided certificates, that may delay the process. Since QR code are sent by email, check your spam and junk folders. Please also clearly write your email adress on the form: without this piece of information, no document could be sent to you.

->I did not received my QR code and I need it to move to France, or to go to museums or restaurants. What can I do?
A temporary QR code could be generated by a healthcare professional following a negative RT-PCR or antigenic test. It is valid for 72 hours. All tests generate a proof as soon as the healthcare professional neters the results, it could be directly printed or sent to you by email, or you may download it on a dedicated website. In France tests are not free for foreigners, but they can easily be performed anywhere. Results are available within 15-20 minutes.
You may look for [local testing facilities](https://www.sante.fr/cf/centres-depistage-covid.html), particularly of the [map of Covid testing](https://www.sante.fr/cf/carte-depistage-covid.html)

->I am a foreign student and I study in a french university or high school.May I ask for a french "pass sanitaire"?
No. These demands will be handled once the students arrive in France.

-> Will you endorse more vacines?
The list of the European Medicines Agency evolves: new market authorization might be given after European Medicines Agency adives, and new equivalences might be reconized by the European Medicines Agency. Look after the list regularly. [More](https://www.gouvernement.fr/info-coronavirus/questions-reponses)

-> Will my "pass sanitaire" be recognied in other countries of EU?
Yes. It make use of the DCC numerical format recognized in the EU and countries having established a mutual agreement with EU.

-> I am not vaccinated. Could you provide me a french QR Code using a certificate stating that I recovered from Covid?
No. The process only recognises vacination in foreign countries. Your recovery certificate is useless for this demand.

-> How much time last the demand?
We do everything we can to rapidely handle your demand.

-> I have a question and I did not find the answer here. Where can I ask for help?
If you don't find the answer to your question here (i.e. on [the page of the french diplomaty departement](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/le-ministere-et-son-reseau/actualites-du-ministere/informations-coronavirus-covid-19/demande-de-passe-sanitaire-en-cas-de-vaccination-a-l-etranger-procedure-pour-64244/))

-> My demand has been refused. Can I appeal the decision?
We firmly encourage you to check that you can ask for this pass. In particular, check that the vacinne you got is on the the list of the European Medecines Agency or equivalent. If your demand failed because the delay after the vaccine was not respected, you may apply for the QR Code at the good date by doing a new demand.

< end of rapid translation>

There are additional requirements listed [on this page of the french diplomaty deparment](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/) depending on where you come from. The base prices for PCR tests is 43€89, antigenic are at 25€. A few euros more may be required for handling fees: asking for a QR Code is a good option!

Comment: This answer is now out of date. One can now only obtain a health pass at a pharmacy within France.